# How can I join mp4 files in Linux without transcoding the files?

Tags: linux, command-line, video

is there a GUI or command-line utility for Linux that would allow me to join several mp4 files into one file? I need to join them in such a way that the original files won't be affected in any way. I mean the audio/video data of the original files won't be touched.

Comment: Maybe this answer [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/2344631) on our sister site StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Write mp4 videos paths into file `input.txt`:

```
file '/path/to/video1.mp4'
file '/path/to/video2.mp4'
```

and then run this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0  -i ./input.txt -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Just this!

Comment: I've edited out the bad use of `sudo` as that is really not needed, and might cause wrong ownership of the resulting file, causing more problems.